# Haskell: Data Type

Tags: haskell, types, instance, ghci

I declare my data to be like this:

```
data Op = Plus | Minus | Mul | Div | Pow
        deriving (Eq, Show)

type Name = String

data Variable a = Variable Name (Expression a)
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Declaration a = Declaration (Variable a)
            deriving (Eq, Show)  

{- The core symbolic manipulation type -}
data Expression a = 
          Number a           -- Simple number, such as 5
        | Expression Op (Expression a) (Expression a)
          deriving (Eq, Show)
```

In GHCi, I want to create a instance of Declaration by typing: 
`Declaration Variable "var1" 2+3`
but it does not work, I guess it is just a wrong syntax, but I cannot figure out how.

Also I would like to know when we need to use instance? This is the code I got from a book:

```
instance Num a => Num (Expression a) where
    a + b = Expression Plus a b
    a - b = Expression Minus a b
    a * b = Expression Mul a b
    negate a = Expression Mul (Number (-1)) a
    abs a = error "abs is unimplemented"
    signum _ = error "signum is unimplemented"
    fromInteger i = Number (fromInteger i)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Declaration Variable "var1" 2+3
```

is equivalent to

```
(Declaration Variable "var1" 2) + 3
```

. That is, it tries to call `Declaration` with 3 arguments (`Variable`, `"var1"`, `2`), then adds the result to `3`. This makes no sense.

You want

```
Declaration (Variable "var1" (2+3))
```